# Enumerating elements generated by Handlebars.js returns nothing on first page load

Tags: javascript, dom, handlebars.js

When trying to access the elements generated by hanlebar.js on first page load I get nothing.
When refreshing the page, everything works as expected.

What I am doing is something like this:

First handlebars creates a set of section elements named "result".
Then I add it to my DOM with a:

```
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', result);
```

Then, with another js plugin this:

```
this.DOM.entries.length
```

Returns 0 and thus I cannot access these elements with a:

```
this.DOM.entries[this.currentPos]
```

Strange how, when I refresh the page everything works as expected, apparently due to browser caching.
How can I overcome this? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to take care of this. I encapsulated my DOM enumerating code in a setTimeout like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 this.DOM.entries.length
...
}, 500);
```

Now it works. Clumsy, as it adds a 500ms delay to the page, but it works.